# Salesforce Community - Main page displays "Try reloading the page or try again later" prompt on page load. What causes this?

Tags: community, liveagent, community-builder, chat

In our primary sandbox environment we had an issue with the main Community page. Whenever the page was loaded in the browser, a prompt would appear reading "Try reloading the page or try again later". The user could clear the issue by clicking an X on the prompt, and everything else worked normally. This was not happening in Production nor in other sandboxes created from Production.

SFDC fixed this issue and it seemed to be a known issue for them, so I'm posting this here for future users who have this issue. Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

SFDC tried removing the CSS/Header code and replacing it, but that didn't work (though it's worth trying).

Then, SFDC Support moved to removing the Chat component. Per their Case comments:

> Upon removing the component and adding it back again the error was
>   gone.
>
> I have noticed the error maybe caused on the Chat deployment. I have
>   noticed that before I removed the component the value set up on the
>   Chat deployment was 'Chat_Deployment'. After I have removed the
>   component and add it back in, the value of the Chat Deployment is
>   'Support'.
>
> I have checked your set up to see if 'Chat_Deployment' is added on the
>   Embedded Service deployments and it seems that it is not. The only
>   deployments is 'Support'"

The Embedded Service Chat Component was on our page and had an incorrect value for "Chat Deployment". Screenshots are for the correct settings.

[image]

[image]